# Endsub on right side not working (reledpar reledmac)

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

I'm having trouble with some problems in reledmac/reledpar. I'd like to use the \startsub and \endsub which is working fine on the left side, but on the right side, the endsub is not working correct. In fact it won't leave the sublinetation again.

Here is an example for the problem, see the footnote numbering.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\title{Edition}
\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
        \pstart\startsub
         {\edtext{Test}{\Afootnote{Test}}}
        \endsub\pend
        \pstart
       Lorem ipsum {\edtext{dolor}{\Afootnote{Test}}} sit amet\\ 
       consetetur sadipscing elitr
       \pend
       \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
        \pstart\startsub
         {\edtext{Test}{\Bfootnote{Test}}}
        \endsub\pend
        \pstart
       Lorem ipsum  {\edtext{dolor}{\Bfootnote{Test}}} sit amet\\ 
       consetetur sadipscing elitr
       \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pairs} 
\Columns

\end{document}
```

Comment: well, that is a bug. So please open a github issue (the method to do it is explained on the handbook)

Comment: Thanks alot @Maïeul
I opened a [bug](https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/898) on github hope I did it correctly. If you have any idea for a workaround I would be happy. Tried to look into it myself, but unfortunately this exceeds my latex skills :(

Comment: well, I hope i Would have time to debug it this week-end, or at least last week-end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The v2.36.0 of reledmac fixes this bug. I have just send it on CTAN. Please ugrade your TeX distribution tomorrow.

Comment: Testet the new version, bug is fixed and the \startsub and \endsub is working fine on the right side now. Thanks again for the quick support.

Comment: please validate the answer, in this case